# Is there any way to install Theano without Nvidia

Tags: installation, theano

I am trying to install Theano on Windows 7 for deep learning. My laptop has no Nvidia GPU. So are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: There should be no problem, so you should better describe the problem you have.

Answer (score 8):

Using the GPU is optional in theano. Calculations can be (and are by default) performed on the CPU instead. If theano complains about a missing CUDA installation, make sure you did not put `device=gpu` in your `%UserProfile%\.theanorc`.

If your laptop has a dedicated graphics card supporting OpenCL, then there is hope: OpenCL support for theano is [in development](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2936).

You might want to read the general guide on how to [install theano on windows](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows).

In any case, deep learning does not go well with laptops, consider using cloud solutions for the actual training.

Disclaimer: I'm not even 50% of an expert here.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to install Theano just fine even without a Nvidia card.

Theano doesn't explicitly require a GPU to be present, although some lasagne layers do and falls back to using Numpy if one isn't present. Not having one doesn't affect it's installation.

To force Theano not to use the GPU (which is non-existent) you can use `force_device=True`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default it works with cpu.

Installing theano with

```
pip install theano
```

Should work with cpu without configuring anything else